# How can I change jest test report output directory?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have jest.config.js as below:

```
module.exports = {
  "roots": [
    "<rootDir>/src"
  ],
  "testMatch": [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)",
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "testResultsProcessor": "jest-sonar-reporter",
  "collectCoverage": true,
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "**/*.{ts,js}",
    "!**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "coverageDirectory": "dist",
  "coverageReporters": ["lcov"]
}
```

A report file `test-report.xml` is generated in the project root directory. How can I make it to be saved in `dist` directory?

Comment: Are you using [jest-junit-reporter](https://github.com/michaelleeallen/jest-junit-reporter)? The `README` states that you need to set the environment variable `TEST_REPORT_PATH` with the desired output path, which in your case would be the `dist` directory.

Comment: I think you are right. Please answer it so I can mark it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment appeared to help, so here it is as an answer:

If you're using [jest-junit-reporter](https://github.com/michaelleeallen/jest-junit-reporter), then you can change the output directory of the generated `test-report.xml` file by setting the `TEST_REPORT_PATH` environment variable with the desired path.

Answer (score 6):

Also you can configure it in `jest` configuration in `package.json` file

```
"jest": {
   "coverageDirectory": "<rootDir>/reports",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your configuration a report file `test-report.xml` is generated by `jest-sonar-reporter`. You can change `jest-sonar-reporter` output directory by adding the following section to `package.json`:

```
"jestSonar": {
  "reportPath": "dist"
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/3dmind/jest-sonar-reporter

Answer (score 1):

You can add --coverageDirectory in your script for test case.

`react-scripts test --coverageDirectory='test-coverage'  --coverage --watchAll=false`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the path like this.

```
coverageReporters: ["json", ["lcov", {"projectRoot": "../../"}]]
```

Comment: I tried that but there is no different. still have the same issue. The test-report.xml file is generated on the root level of the project. And from its name, it sounds like only for coverage report rather than test report.